# Error in Load module in Geodjango

Tags: geodjango, django

I am following this tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/ and did layer mapping. And going along with documentation, I tried the below code

```
from world import load
load.run()
```

And i got an error in shell which is attached below. Why is it so?
I could guess it is due to the NULL value in the attribute. I wanted to know anyone who followed the same documentation got the same?

[image]

Comment: Maybe your shapefile requires different encoding? Latin-2 instead of Latin-1?

Comment: After deleting the feature which has NULL value the error disappears. And when i tried to run the load module again. I could get GDALException<'Invalid pointer returned from "%s" %func.__name__>